# SQL saving shadow table for a column on value change

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

the code that I have now updates the shadow table correctly but the only problem I'm having is that if the email value is the same it will still update the shadow table. This is not want i want. I need the shadow table to update only when the email is changed not updated how could i do this? example "email@email.com" original value should only update if the table changes that value to something different like "secoundemail@gmail.com"

```
CREATE TRIGGER AspNetUsersEmail_trigger
ON AspNetUsers
AFTER UPDATE 
AS
*  IF ( UPDATE (Email) )* what could I use here instead of update?
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[AspNetUserEmailAudit]([UserId],[UserName],[Email],[NormalizedEmail],[FirstName],[LastName])
    SELECT Id,[UserName],[Email],[NormalizedEmail],[FirstName],[LastName] 
    FROM INSERTED
    END;
```

Comment: You know how to do this because your previous question has an answer that contains the logic you need.

Comment: it's the wrong database @SMor

Comment: The "database" does not matter - and your comment makes no sense. IF UPDATE does not do what you think it does - a common misconception. You need to compare the "before" and "after" versions to know if something actually changed. As given in the answer to your previous question, you join the inserted and deleted tables on the primary key columns and you compare the email columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare the `inserted` and `deleted` tables to check if the data has actually been changed.

The easiest way to do this while still taking into account nulls, is to use `EXCEPT`. Make sure to compare against the same primary key.

Note that you can still use `IF(UPDATE` as an early bail-out condition, but it will only bail out if the column was not present at all. It won't work if the column is there but data did not change.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER AspNetUsersEmail_trigger
ON AspNetUsers
AFTER UPDATE 
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF (UPDATE(Email))
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[AspNetUserEmailAudit]
        (UserId, UserName, Email, NormalizedEmail, FirstName, LastName)
    SELECT Id, UserName, Email, NormalizedEmail, FirstName, LastName
    FROM inserted i
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT i.Id, i.Email   -- always include the primary key
                  EXCEPT
                  SELECT d.Id, d.Email
                  FROM deleted d);

GO
```